# multi source/master replcation

Tags: mysql, replication

I'm developing an app [c#], with a database as data source, which will be run both offline and online.
I have three MySQL databases which have the same structure, one is in a server and the two others in tablets;
I want to keep those databases synchronized but the tablets can't their IPs unchanged.
I did some research on internet but I didn't find what I'm really looking for.

https://www.percona.com/blog/2013/10/02/mysql-5-7-multi-source-replication/ my problem is that the tablets will be connected from different places, and I don't know how to configure them as the master because tablets will change their host_name

Comment: If it's local can't you just use `127.0.0.1`, `localhost` or [any other loopback address](https://superuser.com/questions/255835/whats-a-loopback-address-i-e-127-0-0-1)?

Comment: each tablets has a local database, I have the same database structure in the server, and I want keep those 3 databases synchronized, and if update the tablet's database 1 I want that the database in the tablet 2 and also the server's DB be updated

Comment: create a master master replication from each tablet to the db server. so you can change in any database and its replicated to each other. the only thing is the auto increment. you must configure so that 3 is the incremet and the offset is 1 for db 2 for tablet one and 3 for the other